# RegEx to match text to first occurence of a delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the data I want to match with RegEx:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font size="4">Speciality</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font size="4">somespeciality</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font size="4">Date</font>
    </td>
    <td>
      <font size="4">somedate</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get as a result `somespeciality` but with this RexEx:

```
/Speciality[\s\S]*size="4">(.*?)<\/font>/i
```

I'm getting `somedate`. What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, and unrelated to your problem, the [`<font>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated and obsolete. Please, use css instead.

Comment: Please see [*RegEx match open tags…*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @DavidThomas actually I'm dealing with data on an oldy website trying to get them then store them in a SQLite database.

Comment: @RobG Yep this post crossed my path a few times.. lol but really I'm compelled to do so.. DOM traversal and other techniques would be more complicated to implement for me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a **non**-[**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) quantifier after your character class.

```
[\s\S]*?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, if you did want to do this with plain DOM methods, you'd do something like the following. It gets all the elements, finds the first one with text content that matches the text, gets it's tagname, then finds the next element with that tag name and returns the text content:

```
var data = '<table><tr><td><font size="4">Speciality</font></td>' +
           '<td><font size="4">somespeciality</font></td></tr>' +
           '<tr><td><font size="4">Date</font></td><td><font size="4">' +
           'somedate</font></td></tr></table>';

function getSpecial(text, data) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = data;
  var tagName;

  var nodes = div.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (tagName && nodes[i].tagName == tagName) {
      return nodes[i].textContent;
    }

    if (nodes[i].textContent.trim() == text) {
      tagName = nodes[i].tagName;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getSpecial('Speciality', data)); // somespeciality
```

The difficulty with any such approach (including using a regular expression) is that any change to the markup (and resulting DOM) will likely cause the process to fail.

Note that the above requires ES5 and support for *textContent*, which should be all modern browsers and IE 9+. Support for older browsers can be added by adding a polyfill for *trim* and using `nodes[i].textContent || nodes[i].innerText`. The rest will be fine.

Comment: Thank you! That's a correct answer to my problem too. But regarding performance will this have same performance? (I'm loading with ajax over 12000 pages one by one matching 15 strings.. with This code http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=57kPXWNA with XSS in a webkit)